# wordpress to import joomla articles

Tags: plugins

I am using wordpress plugin `Joomla 1.5 Importer` to import articles from joomla. My joomla version is 1.5, but when i tried to import i get this error

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'www.ashramyoga.com' (110) in /home/aaa/public_html/aaa/aaa/wp-content/plugins/joomla-15-importer/joomla-15-importer.php on line 177
```

Answer (score 2):

Your server doesn't have [MySQL Improved Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) enabled. Depending on your host, you can normally enable this via php.ini - see notes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).